# Blazor - зачем в @code{} обращаться к БД через await Task.Run(() =>....запрос к БД...)?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, blazor-server-side

В примере на сайте
[Blazor пример](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/blazor-crud-app-using-entity-framework-core-in-net-5/)
в разделе Employees.Razor есть обращение к БД

```
@code {
List<Employee> EmpObj;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    EmpObj = await Task.Run(() => employeeService.GetAllEmployeesAsync());
}
```

**Зачем использовать/оборачивать в Task.Run,**

**если можно обратится "напрямую" EmpObj = await employeeService.GetAllEmployeesAsync() ??**

Или тут какая-то особенность Blazor?
Или автор делает лишнюю работу?

Насколько я понимаю, оборачивать в await Task.Run(()=>синхронный метод)
был бы смысл СИНХРОННОГО метода, а в примере employeeService.GetAllEmployeesAsync()
и так асинхронный.

Comment: c-sharpcorner - это уголок непуганых индусокодеров. Поэтому не стоит удивляться наличию танцующих слонов в коде. Там вполне может быть что-то полезное, как этот туториал в целом, но не стоит удивляться таким несуразностям при ближайшем рассмотрении.

Comment: Автор делает лишнюю работу.